# react-dropzone-uploader AVI file stuck on status "preparing"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-dropzone

With react-dropzone-uploader set up like this:

```
<Dropzone
  getUploadParams={ getUploadParams }
  onChangeStatus={ handleChangeStatus }
  accept='video/*'
  inputContent={ inputContent }
  styles={{
    dropzoneReject: { borderColor: 'red', backgroundColor: '#DAA' }
    , inputLabel: ( files, extra ) => ( extra.reject ? { color: 'red' } : {} )
  }}
/>
```

Uploading a 250mb .avi file gets stuck in "preparing" status. Suggestions?

Works fine with mp4 files.

```
const getUploadParams = meta => ::
  return ::
    url: '/'
```

Comment: I have the same issue, and raised an issue on Github: https://github.com/fortana-co/react-dropzone-uploader/issues/44

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this bug was just fixed in `2.10.2`.

> I just pushed a fix in 2.10.2 that ensures that generatePreview returns a promise that never takes more than 1s to resolve or reject.
>
> This way file types for which onload or onloadedmetadata aren't called don't return promises that hang forever.
>
> 1s is still more than enough time to get the metadata for even huge (~5gb files), but isn't so long that it's a huge annoyance for file types that don't support metadata retrieval.

https://github.com/fortana-co/react-dropzone-uploader/issues/44

Sorry it took a while to get this fixed, I've been busy at work and not until recently did I have time to spend on maintaining and improving RDU.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry about the late response.